Change one widget by clicking on it in ListView
I need help with this task. This is a test version. In my real project, I get data from the server, namely the id and username. I need to change the color of a certain ListTile by clicking on IconButton.
class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: ids.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: MyListTile(
            index: index,
            id: ids[index],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyListTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyListTile({
    super.key,
    required this.index,
    required this.id,
  });
  final int index;
  final int id;

  @override
  State<MyListTile> createState() => _MyListTileState();
}

class _MyListTileState extends State<MyListTile> {
  bool clicked = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: clicked ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Text('id: ${widget.id}, index: ${widget.index}'),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  !clicked;
                });
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 30)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

List<int> ids = [500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510];


It is necessary to remember the ID depending on the pressed list item. Most likely, I need to compare the selected ID and the ID of the tile. Maybe fuction indexWhere() will be good.

use onTap callback or use state managers like bloc or provider.
class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const StartPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: ids.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: MyListTile(
            index: index,
            id: ids[index],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MyListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyListTile({super.key,     required this.index,
    required this.id,onTap});
  final int index;
  final int id;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: clicked ? Colors.blue : Colors.transparent,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          Text('id: ${widget.id}, index: ${widget.index}'),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: onTap,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle, size: 30),),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

